# Visual Studio 2015 debugger not executing derived class virtual function override?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, virtual-functions

Here is a minimal working example tested in Visual Studio 2015:

```
class A
{
   virtual void X() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual bool Y() { return false; }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
   virtual bool Y() override { return true; }
};

int main()
{
   B* b = new C;

   bool result = b->Y();
}
```

The value of `result` is `true` as expected.  However, the watch expression `b->Y()` evaluates to `false`.

If I comment out the virtual function `X` in class `A` above then both `result` and `b-Y()` evaluated in a watch expression are `true`.

It appears to me that the debugger evaluation engine is only respecting the topmost virtual table in an inheritance chain... is this correct? And is there anything I can do to work around this?

Comment: No introspection in C++, the debugging engine just has no idea that `b` is actually C*.  Only a C++ compiler can get this right, the debugger does not have one built in.  Please don't waste your time on the silly answer from the Microsoft employee.

Comment: @Hans Passant, sorry for that if I provide the wrong answer, I just repro it in my side, I get the same result as Micah, but if I enable the "Use Native Compatibility Mode", value of b-Y() in watch window was true. Not very sure that whether it was the debugger option issue, but I agree with you, VC++ would be better for this issue. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @HansPassant If I comment out the definition of `X` then the debugger correctly will call `C`'s implementation of `Y`

Comment: That happens, no more thunking required to get the correct v-table pointer.  The kind of thing that only the C++ compiler knows how to do correctly.  Do consider that you can simply help and use `((C*)b)->Y()`.  But it isn't always obvious that it is a C* when you're buried deep in interfaced-based code.  Such are the hazards of C++, if it was easy then anybody could do it and we can't have that now can we :)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT "Use Native Compatibility Mode" does seem to fix the issue in the sample above, but it leaves me unable to set breakpoints in my real application and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx) seems to suggest I'd be giving other things up with this option as well.